# Scroll event not getting fired for a div

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jQuery dialog widget. The html rendered for that dialog is shown below in the jsFiddle. Scroll bars can be seen in the outer div but the scroll event is not firing.

http://jsfiddle.net/dM5kY/

Adding below javascript does not fire the event:

```
$("#dialog).scroll(function(){
 alert("scroll");
});

$("#dialog").on('scroll',function(){
   alert("scroll 1");
});
```

Comment: jQuery library not added! `"` quotes are not ended properly!

Comment: selector `$("#dialog)` should be `$("#dialog")`. Also, in your fiddle, you are scrolling `window` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my update here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JeekOnline/dM5kY/21/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("#dialog").scroll(function(){
    alert("scroll");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not added jquery library. here is the updated jquery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#dialog').scroll(function(){
      alert("scroll");
    });
})
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dM5kY/18/

Answer (score 2):

There are several error:

1. missing jQuery library
2. *dialog* height should be less then *modal* height otherwise scroll wont appear
3. set CSS property overflow: scroll

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/dM5kY/19/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").on('scroll', function(){
        alert("scroll 1");
    });
});
```